# How can I delete some objects in scene during the build pipeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to delete some object in the scene when I build the package. Because of these objects use for the Editor only.
I don't want to build all these objects in the package, it's useless and I need to remove them when I run these scenes.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Unity provide settings to use object for only editor 'EditorOnly' as I uploaded screenshot here. so it won't be exist on the build

Comment: Thank you for helping me. this is very useful for me.